# Newton-Raphson method for complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, newton-raphson

The Newton-Raphson Method as we know it is
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f\left(x_n\right)}{f'\left(x_n\right)}$$
Where $x$ is solution of $f\left(x\right)=0$
But What if we have a equation of the form $$xe^x=i$$
Can we apply Newton-Raphson method treating $i$ as constant or we have to substitute $x=a+ib$ and solve two simultaneous equations.
Can you help me please?

Comment: We can even use it for matrices although I can't quite explain why it works.

Comment: If $A$ is a matrix can we find $Log_{ }A$ or something like that

Comment: I have mostly tried polynomial because they often have nice convergence properties for Newton rhapsody

Comment: Bless you automatic correct!

Comment: @mathreadler we can find $e^A$ by using expansion of $e^x$

Comment: Yes we can often define matrix functions as power series expansions if we do matrix multiplication instead of scalar multiplication

Comment: @mathreadler I was wondering whether $|f\left(A\right)|=f\left(|A|\right)$

Comment: Take care : there is an infinite number of solutions to your equation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici how?

Comment: As I wrote in comments, ofr $x=a+i b$ with $a=0$, you need to solve for $b$ the equation $b \,e^{b \tan (b)} \sec (b)-1=0$. Plot this function for $-20 \leq b \leq 20$. How many roots do you see ?

Comment: Yeah you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robert Israel answered, the work to be done is the same and the same problems are faced, in particular the choice of $x_0$.

Using $x_0=1+i$, the first iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.0000000000+1.0000000000\, i \\
 1 & 0.5635771723+0.8175944690\, i \\
 2 & 0.3765837446+0.6414532983\, i \\
 3 & 0.3713945744+0.5772934579\, i \\
 4 & 0.3747064835+0.5764066745\, i \\
 5 & 0.3746990207+0.5764127230\, i
\end{array}
\right)$$
Using $x_0=1$, the  first iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.0000000000+0.0000000000\, i \\
 1 & 0.5000000000+0.1839397206\, i \\
 2 & 0.2776785639+0.4861083567\, i \\
 3 & 0.3775795796+0.5918579469\, i \\
 4 & 0.3745261046+0.5765158277\, i \\
 5 & 0.3746990317+0.5764126917\, i
\end{array}
\right)$$
Using $x_0=i$, the  first iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.0000000000+1.0000000000\, i \\
 1 & 0.1908866453+0.3494156605\, i \\
 2 & 0.3588322329+0.6585981708\, i \\
 3 & 0.3690703346+0.5754839470\, i \\
 4 & 0.3747254289+0.5764171936\, i \\
 5 & 0.3746990213+0.5764127231\, i
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Can we try it by substituting $x=a+ib$

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary. You can do it but then you will have to solve two equations for $a,b$. Newton-Raphson would work (making probably the problem more difficult).

Comment: But in your method iteration will be very difficult with complex numbers

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary. You can solve $$e^a (a \cos (b)-b \sin (b))=0$$ $$e^a (a \sin (b)+b \cos (b))=1$$

Comment: These are easily possible with scientific calculator but your one need some manual work

Comment: @abhishekchaudhary. In this case, which is easy, for sure. Eliminate $a=b\,\tan(b)$ from the first and solve $b\, e^{b \tan (b)} \sec (b)=1$ for $b$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77417/discussion-between-abhishek-chaudhary-and-claude-leibovici).

Comment: Take care that there is an infinite number of solutions. Ask Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 2):

Newton-Raphson is exactly the same for equations involving complex numbers.  You just have to do the arithmetic using complex numbers.

Comment: Can you solve the above equation for me